# AWS-Lambda: Unable to add another event, unhelpful GenerateChangeSet failure message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to add another path to AWS Lambda that has been generated by code star.

I have tried to add the following events (in different commits) with the same failure behavior.

```
HelloWorld:
 Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
 Properties:
   Events:
      API:
          Type:
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
```

```
HelloWorld:
 Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
 Properties:
   Events:
      Decks_GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /decks
            Method: get
```

GenerateChangeSet step in code pipeline fails with the following unhelpful message:

```
Action execution failed
Failed to create change set. Current status: FAILED
```

When going to 'Details' Link of GenerateChangeSet step. It just takes me to Stack view without any particular stack or execution event selected.

What are the steps to troubleshoot this? Any suggestions on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't want to create a changeset, you presumably have a syntax error in your document. However, since you've not shared the CloudFormation template, that is hard to determine.

If you want to troubleshoot this, you can try to manually create a change set (that might provide more error information), or you can use [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint) to do some static code analysis on your CloudFormation template.

Comment: or if you have the SAM CLI tool installed, just run >sam validate